# Sql Server call from Java error

Tags: java, sql-server

I have the following code in Java class:

```
CallableStatement stmt = con.prepareCall({ call myInsert( ?, ?, ?)});
stmt.setString(1, myTO.getField1());
stmt.setString(2, myTO.getField2());
stmt.setString(3, myTO.getField3());
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

And `myInsert` in database is defined as:

```
IF OBJECT_ID ( 'myInsert', 'P' ) IS NOT NULL   
DROP PROCEDURE myInsert;  

GO 

CREATE PROCEDURE [myInsert]
@Field1 as uniqueidentifier,
@Field2 as varchar(120),
@Field3 as varchar(120)
@myId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER OUTPUT

AS

SET @myId = NEWID()

INSERT INTO myTable
     (myID, Field1, Field2, Field3) 
    VALUES ( @myID, @Field1, @Field2, @Field3 )
```

However, the call is failing with below error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Procedure or function 'myInsert' expects parameter '@myId', which was not supplied.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:232)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1672)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:460)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:405)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7535)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2438)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:208)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:183)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:348)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:98)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:98)
```

What am I doing wrong ? How can I resolve this issue ?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're missing your out parameter.

```
CallableStatement stmt = con.prepareCall("{ call myInsert(?, ?, ?, ?)}");
stmt.setString(1, myTO.getField1());
stmt.setString(2, myTO.getField2());
stmt.setString(3, myTO.getField3());
stmt.registerOutParameter(4, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
stmt.executeUpdate();
System.out.println(stmt.getString(4)); // <-- print @myId
```

Comment: Thank you.. that was what was missing!